# "Inspiration" mean "a sudden feeling of enthusiasm"?

Tags: word-meaning

"Inspiration" in Macmillan, http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/inspiration,
 means " a sudden feeling of enthusiasm, or a new idea that helps you to do or create something".

I am wondering which example use "in spiration" as "a sudden feeling of enthausism".I think the examples below all uses "inspiration" as "a new idea" rather than "a sudden feeling of enthausism. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think so. Did you check the definitions of the 2 words to see if there is any common ground?

Comment: How about if *you* give an example of how you would like to use the word, and what you hope it will mean?

Answer (score 1):

"After watching the weight loss TV show, I was inspired to get off the couch and go jogging"

It can be used in much the same way as the word "motivated".

Comment: I know "inspire" could be used in this way. What confused me is the word "inspiration" rather than "inspire".

Comment: "The football coach's half-time pep-talk was an inspiration to his team."  (it was like a breath of new energy)